# pandas list of dataframes very slow

Tags: python, pandas

I have a image sequence with 200 images. Each image shows several clusters from a explosion experiment. Now I want to create statistics over time. Therefore I divided my task into two subscripts:

1. An python script which does the image processing. Done by opencv with findContour, ConvexHull, ConnectedComponentsWithStats, etc. For every single image i serialize my data as pandas dataframe to pickle. Size of all pickle files ~13MB
2. An juypter notebook, which loads all dataframes into a list. But a major problem occured. Dataspell is very very slow (cannot load variables in efficient time, needs longer than normal for cell execution, creating a single plot needs minutes). I think the list creation is responsible for the slowdown. How could i save my data better? Is pandas multiindex a good choice if i have two dimension like time and number of clusters with all its parameters?

Thank you for your help

My code added:

```py
import pandas as pd
import glob
folder = "dataframes_Versuch_T3_5_4g_Clusters"
fListGeo = glob.glob(os.path.join(folder, 'geometry','*'))
fListStats = glob.glob(os.path.join(folder, 'statistic','*'))

dfListGeo = []
dfListStats = []
for f1,f2 in tqdm(zip(fListGeo,fListStats)):
    dfListGeo.append(pd.read_pickle(f1))
    dfListStats.append(pd.read_pickle(f2))
```

Comment: If you can please share  with us the code of the second point, it would be easier to help!

Comment: Hello Phoenix,
Yes of course I added my code to the original question

Comment: Strange, I did my calculations with Dataspell. When I switched to VScode everything works well. Seems Dataspell is buggy with this topic.

Comment: So the same code in jupyter and Dataspell but when you run the code on DataSpell, it takes long time to finish, right?

Comment: If you know the size of the list, you can initialize first the size of the list.

Comment: Yes dataspell seems much slower. But after some tests with VSCode it seems to also slow down and simple calculations does not finish. Maybe i will create a new Aanaconda environment. Maybe i have some package troubles :-/

Comment: You can use google colab, it is faster

Comment: Ok thank you for the advice. But I am just wondering, cause I am doing high expensive image processing calculations and now i have troubles with data structures of 13MB :-(